# Overriding innerHTML property access

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking for a way to enable setter method on a DOM element. So basically I want to intercept all calls to this specific property. I've tried with defining get/set properties on a specific DOM element, but it isn't of much help:

```
(function(object, property) {
    var __value;
    Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
        // Create a new getter for the property
        get: function () {
            console.log('access gettter');
            return __value;
        },
        // Create a new setter for the property
        set: function (val) {
            __value = val;
        }
    })
})(document.body, 'innerHTML');
```

The result of this is that calling:

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'testValue';
```

is:

```
document.body.innerHTML
 access gettter
"testValue"
```

However this doesn't have any impact on the page, I mean body of the page isn't changed, just the value of a private variable inside the closure is returned. Is there a way to achieve this functionality in JavaScript ?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Altering host objects is a Bad Idea. http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this can be done. Here is the code in working form:

```
(function(object, property) {
    var ownObjectProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
    // exit if bad property
    if (!object[property]) {
        console.error(property + " is not a property of " + object.toString());
        return;
    }

    while (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ownObjectProto, property)) {
        ownObjectProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(ownObjectProto);
    }

    var ownProperty = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ownObjectProto, property);
    Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
        // Create a new getter for the property
        get: function () {
            console.log('access gettter');
            return ownProperty.get.call(this);
        },
        // Create a new setter for the property
        set: function (val) {
            return ownProperty.set.call(this, val);
        }
    })
})(document.body, 'innerHTML');
```

You are not actually replacing the set and get functions here, but you are able to augment them. Seriously though, you shouldn't use this unless you have a very particular need for it, and you really know what you are doing. If not used properly, you could really screw up the functionality of plug-ins on your page or any other number of unintended consequences.

I also have a playground fiddle here:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jderjLn6/)

Comment: Regarding if (!object[property]) won't that evaluate to true and return if the property is defined on the object but happens to have a falsey value (false, empty string, zero)?